# Is there any effect on the physical properties when the size of the system increases in DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, physical-properties-of-materials, periodic-boundary-conditions

I am using Quantum ESPRESSO to do some DFT calculations. I want to know if **the optoelectronic properties** obtained by a **unit cell** would remain the same when the properties are obtained by using a larger **supercell**.

Comment: Do you mean a) Are the answers different when you use open boundary conditions compared to periodic boundary conditions? or b) When using periodic boundary conditions can the the answers depend upon the size of the supercell you use?

Comment: @IanBush the OP confirmed that he is indeed asking (b)

Comment: It would be good if you could unpack what you mean by optoelectronic properties in terms of the exact quantities you are interested in. e.g. band structure, dielectric function and absorption spectra, etc.

Comment: @CW Tan
yes optical ( Dielectric  function, refraction index...) and electronic propreties (DOS, PDOS,Band structure..)

Comment: As long as the supercell is exactly a periodic reproduction of the original unit cell and the computational parameters are equivalent (be especially careful with the k point sampling) you should get *exactly* the same, except possibly with a trivial scaling (e.g. the total energy). You are studying the same system, just exploiting symmetry differently.

Comment: When you are doing calculations, you should always check how the studied properties converge by changing cell size / k point space (the two are interconnected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer to your question. Here I discuss the effect of the size of supercell on DOS, PDOS, and band structure. Others can add the effect on optical or other electronic properties. As pointed out by Ian Bush in the comment, *as long as the supercell is exactly a periodic reproduction of the original unit cell and ... the computational parameters are equivalent, you should get exactly the same, except possibly with a trivial scaling*. When I ran a calculation of a carbon chain using 1,2,3,4, and 8 atoms per supercell, I found that the total energy scales almost exactly linearly.

Like the total energy, the DOS also scales linearly (mostly). So for example, if you did your calculation with 2 atoms per supercell and found the DOS as 3 states/eV at some E. Then, you will find the DOS to be 6 states/eV at the same E if you used 4 atoms per supercell. The same thing is true with PDOS.

For the band structure, if you use a larger supercell, then we have a phenomenon called *band folding*. See [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/700/why-is-the-band-structure-of-a-supercell-more-dense-than-for-simple-cell/750#750) and [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8835/different-band-structure-in-supercell-but-not-due-to-band-folding) questions about band folding and unfolding. Very briefly, for a larger supercell, the band structure will be more densely populated.